# Free Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, websites, cpanel

I wanna build up an e-commerce site using magento 2 with zero cost.

Is there, any website where I can get free domain and free hosting. And it will give access me to use softaculas installer to install software free?

Comment: I think there isn`t any website where you can get domain or host for free :) .

Comment: @YIgen 000webhost.com is available. But limited with softaculas. Only WordPress. :( I need magento installed by softaculas.

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think that there are sites which provide free domain to you. Yes some them offer but with very limited resources  which is not enough for running magento 2.So i suggest  if you want to create a website on magento compare  service providers and check weather magento 2 will work in that environment  or not.